# Intersect many list by one property

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, intersect

I have `List<List<ProductFilter>>`

```
public class ProductFilter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FilterValueId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? FilterId { get; set; }
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
    public string FilterName { get; set; }
}
```

And I want `Intersect` by `ProductId` and return `ProductFilter`. It`s possible?
I try it:

```
var intersection = groupList
  .Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => previousList
     .Select(x => x.ProductId)
     .Intersect(nextList.Select(x => x.ProductId))
  .ToList());
```

but it give me error because return `int`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`'
>   to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<ProductFilter>`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving the said error because the accumulator function is expected to return the *same type as the elements in the source* for this specific overload of [**`Aggregate`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___0___0__) i.e. `List<ProductFilter>` instead of `List<int>`.

To yield a `IEnumerable<int>` as a result, first project to `IEnumerable<int>` and then call `Aggregate`:

```
groupList.Select(p => p.Select(e => e.ProductId))
         .Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => previousList.Intersect(nextList));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use the overload of [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Intersect__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) which accepts an [`IEqualityComparer<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
class ProductFilterProductIdEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductFilter>
{
    public bool Equals(ProductFilter x, ProductFilter y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.ProductId == y.ProductId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductFilter obj) => obj.ProductId;
}
```

```
var productFilterProductIdEqualityComparer = new ProductFilterProductIdEqualityComparer();
var intersection = groupList
    .Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => 
        previousList.Intersect(nextList, productFilterProductIdEqualityComparer)
    .ToList());
```

---

**Note:** Keep in mind that when two `ProductFilter` have the same `ProductId` but differs on other properties you will only get the first one in `intersection`